# ruby, error creating a hash

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, copy, copy-paste, paste

Trying to create an array or has of ids and names but

```
@campaign_ids_and_names = Hash.new
@campaign_ids.each do |cid|
  @campaign_ids_and_names.merge!(cid => Campaign.find(cid, :user => current_user).name)
end
@campaign_ids_and_names
```

keeps just returning 1

I know the ID's do exist in the Campaign table.
I think the issue is more my knowledge of how to create 1 array or hash from another.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
@campaign_ids_and_names = Hash.new
@campaign_ids.each do |cid|
  @campaign_ids_and_names[cid] = Campaign.find(cid, :user => current_user).name
end
@campaign_ids_and_names
```

You should also checkout Active Record associations : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Which will help you clean up what you're trying to do even more into something like:

```
@campaign_ids_and_names = Hash.new
@campaign_ids.each do |cid|
  @campaign_ids_and_names[cid] = current_user.campaigns.find(cid).name
end
@campaign_ids_and_names
```